# $(modules:.ko:.o) Advanced Features for Reference to Variables

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel, gnu-make

I can't understand Grammar of makefile
`_modpost: $(if $(KBUILD_MODPOST_NOFINAL), $(modules:.ko:.o),$(modules))`,
when i browse kernel in scripts/Makefile.modpost at  https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/ea837f1c050344c3f884531a195c6e339b1a54e8#diff-742ab4bcbdb44545def9a3982e0ac3b0.
what does it mean?`$(modules:.ko:.o)`
Isn't Advanced Features for Reference to Variables?
like Substitution References?`bar := $(foo:.o=.c)`
why don't use `$(modules:.ko=.o)` instead of `$(modules:.ko:.o)`?
where can i find the grammer to explain `$(modules:.ko=.o)`???

Answer (score 0):

That is not special GNU make syntax of any kind.  The statement `$(modules:.ko:.o)` is simply a reference to the variable named, literally, `modules:.ko:.o`.  If that variable exists then its value would be replaced.  If the variable doesn't exist, then it's replaced with the empty string.

With no information other than your question I'd say that there's an error in the makefile.  I recommend you ask the Linux kernel folks, not us on StackOverflow :)

Comment: I only find syntax of Substitution References in 6.3.1 Substitution References at https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Substitution-Refs. 
I have ask Sam Ravnborg  committer for help,thanks.
Because i can't find any syntax  to explain $(modules:.ko:.o),i want to verify whether it is reasonable syntax.

Comment: I guess it's not correct answer. This definitely has a special meaning. Variable name is `modules`.

Comment: No that's not true.  GNU make treats `$(modules:.ko:.o)` as just a simple variable named `modules:.ko:.o`.  There's no special GNU make facility that treats that variable in a different way.  If someone believes there is please provide an example makefile showing the special behavior.